# How To Have a Console Application Create a New Mail Message in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, console-application, email

I am trying to figure out a way to write a C# console application in Visual Studio that will take a string of ";" separated email addresses and create a New Mail Message (in Microsoft Outlook) addressed to the contacts in the string.

In other words, is there a way to take a string in a console application and then open up an Untitled Message in Outlook with that string in the "To..." field. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Outlook APIs? I'm sure there are examples there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write

```
Process.Start("mailto:a@example.com,b@example.com");
```

This will open the user's default mail client.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use outlook specific [command-line switches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx) then do:

```
Process.Start("[path to outlook]/Outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "email1@email.com;email2@email.com"
```